# Error with Uploading Image on Twilio WhatsApp when Integrated with Dialogflow

Tags: twilio, dialogflow-es, whatsapp, twilio-api, twilio-programmable-chat

I have a Dialogflow chatbot set up which is integrated with the Twilio WhatsApp API. It's all good when I type text on WhatsApp, but I receive this error on Twilio debugger when I post an image or a video on WhatsApp:

> **Error - 12300 Invalid Content-Type**
>
> Twilio is unable to process the Content-Type of the provided URL. 
>   Please see the Twilio Markup XML Documentation for more information on
>   valid Content-Types. You must return a Content-Type for all requests.
>   Requests without a Content-Type will appear in the Debugger as a 502
>   Bad Gateway error.
>
> **Possible Causes:**
>
> Having a phone number, outgoing call request or action attribute refer
>   to a non-XML or audio resource. Having a Play verb attempt to play
>   non-audio content, such as XML or text.
>
> **Possible Solutions:**
>
> Verify that that your web server is returning a Content-Type and it is
>   the expected value Make sure the URL noted refers to a valid resource

I have checked it on both Dialogflow and Twilio consoles but I am not sure which configuration I have to set up for image uploading to work.

Answer (score 0):

Currently media isn't supported with WhatsApps integration, so that would explain the issue.

Receiving a WhatsApp message

https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/whatsapp/api#receiving-a-whatsapp-message

"Support for Inbound media and location is coming soon."

Answer (score 0):

Twilio now accept media on WhatsApp messages, the "Body" parameter is empty and you can access media information in other request parameters:

```
{
  "MediaUrl0": "https://api.twilio.com/2021-04-01/Accounts/ABC...",
  "MediaContentType0": "image/jpeg",
  "NumMedia": "1",
  ...
}
```

This also maybe help:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dialogflow-integrations/pull/18